# explicit .diff file out generation from svn eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn

Within the eclipse Java editor, `right click -> Compare With` between `Working copy` and `base revision` opens the diff between the versions within the Eclipse compare editor.

Is there a way to get the actual .diff as a file i.e

```
Index: Something.java
===================================================================
--- Something.java  (revision 10155)
+++ Something.java  (revision 10154)
@@ -227,9 +227,6 @@
 import ...
 import ...
 import ...
-import com...
-import com...
-import com...
+import com....
```

from within eclipse without using the shell svn diff command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Didn't realize it. Quite simple!

```
Java Editor -> Right click -> Team -> Create Patch
```

Answer (score 4):

You have a *Create Patch* command available in several context menus, like the *Team* sub menu when selecting a file, or when selecting a change in the *Synchronize* perspective.

Personally I find the most convinient way to browse the history of a resource in the *History* view, to select 2 different revisions and then to invoke the command from the context menu of the selection.